# Return a dataframe to a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to take a list of "ID"s from my dataframe dfrep and pass the column with the ID into a function I created in order to pass the values into a query to return back to dfrep.

My function is returning a dataframe, but the results of the dataframe are including the header and when I print dfrep there are two lines. I also cannot write the dataframe to excel using xlwings because I get TypeError: must be a pywintypes time object (got DataFrame).

```py
def overrides(id):
    sql = f"select name from sales..rep where id in({id})"

    mydf = pd.read_sql(sql, conn)

    return mydf

overrides = np.vectorize(overrides)
dfrep['name'] = overrides(dfrep['ID'])

wsData.range('A1').options(pd.DataFrame,index=False).value = dfrep
```

My goal is to load the column(s) in my function's dataframe into my main dataframe dfrep and then write to excel via xlwings. Any help is appreciated.